# Wordpress getting the woocommerce thumnail when printing

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the thumnail image when I print the order information for a woocommerce order, but I am getting some errors.

This is my code:

```
<?php $items = wcdn_get_order_items(); if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item ) : ?><tr>
                            <td class="description"><?php echo $item['name']; ?> <br><br>Excerpt:<?php $excerpt = $item['product']->post->post_excerpt; echo $excerpt; ?>
                                                             <br><br>Image:<?php echo $item['product']->post->post_thumbnail; ?>
```

The excert bit works fine, but I am am not getting the image - I am not getting a php error, but there is no image either - I am just trying to get the thumbnail.

My knowledge of wordpress/php isnt brilliant, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use [get_the_post_thumbnail();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) ? It would give you an image you could use. In your example it would be something like:

```
<?php $items = wcdn_get_order_items(); if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item ) : ?><tr>
          <td class="description"><?php echo $item['name']; ?> <br><br>Excerpt:<?php $excerpt = $item['product']->post->post_excerpt; echo $excerpt; ?>
          <br><br>Image:<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($item['product']->post->ID);  ?>
```

I am not entirely sure what id to give the function, but i am sure you will figure that out.